# Display link from XML using PHP simpleXML

Tags: php

Here is the code I have written, It should fetch the first entry in the atom feed from GitHub and display the commit description and a link to the commit on GitHub:

```
$url = "https://github.com/moodle/moodle/commits/master.atom";
$rss = simplexml_load_file($url);
if($rss) {
$items = $rss->entry;
$i = 0;
foreach($items as $item) {
    $title = $item->title;
    $link = $item->link;
    echo '<li class="github">';
    echo '<span>GitHub - moodle:master</span>';
    foreach($link as $links) {
        echo $links->href;
        echo "<a href=".$links->href.">";
    }
    echo $title;
    echo '</a>';
    echo "</li>";

            if(++$i == 1) break;
}
}
```

However I do not seem to be able to display the href from the link entity.

Can anyone explain or adjust the code to get the link displaying?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Elements and attributes are handled differently in SimpleXML.  You should be able to pull it out like this instead:

```
foreach($link as $links) {
    echo $links['href'];
    echo "<a href=".$links['href'].">";
}
```

Also, you can check http://www.php.net/manual/en/simplexml.examples-basic.php to see some simple usage examples.